# How to replace 'Async=false' with promise in javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, promise

I have read a lot about `promises` but I'm still not sure how to implement it.

I wrote the folowing AJAX call with `async=false` in order for it to work, but I want to replace it with promise as I saw that `async=false` is deprecated.

```
self.getBalance = function (order) {
    var balance;
    $.ajax({
        url: "/API/balance/" + order,
        type: "GET",
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            balance = data;
        },
        done: function (date) {
        }
    });
    return balance;
}
```

Would you be able to help me? I just need an example to understand it.

Comment: May be you should try to structure your logic to avoid async=false behaviors, If you are learning promises you should try to load things with promises each time you need them, but you can decide to catch them or not inside the promise method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Return promise object from `getBalance` method:

```
self.getBalance = function (orderNumber) {
    return $.ajax({
        url: "/Exchange.API/accountInfo/balance/" + orderNumber,
        type: "GET"
    });
}
```

and use it later like this:

```
service.getBalance().then(function(balance) {
    // use balance here
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, can you just give me a short explanation? Will `then` execute anyway? (fail or succeed)

Comment: The first method on then executes on success. You can add a second methods as parameter that executes when it fails. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then

Comment: `then` takes two callback functions that will be executed when response from server has loaded: `then(function successCallback(response) { /* data loaded successfully */ }, function errorCallback(error) { console.log(error); })`.

Comment: Thank you very much, I got it to work perfectly, thank you!!

Answer (score 5):

As first point, you don't want to set an asynchronous call to false as it will lock the UI.

You could simplify your method returning the ajax object and the handle it as a promise.

```
self.getBalance = function (orderNumber) {    
    return $.ajax({
        url: "/Exchange.API/accountInfo/balance/" + orderNumber,
        type: "GET",
    });
};
var demoNumber = 12;
self.getBalance(demoNumber).then(function(data){
    console.log(data);
},function(err){
    console.log("An error ocurred");
    console.log(err);
});
```