# How to asynchronously iterate over array with javascript & promises

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

can someone help me with asynchronously iterating over an array using javascript & promises? Here is a simplified breakdown of what I am trying to achieve - I have an array of products that I want to insert into a database. Many of the products in the array are duplicates. Therefore, my algorithm is:

1. check if product's product code is already in the database
2. if it is in the database, look @ the next product
3. if it is NOT in the database, insert the product

I am having issues doing this asynchronously. Here is my code so far:

```
var checkIfProductExists = function(product_code) {

        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

            db.collection('products').find( {product_code: product_code } ).toArray(function(err, res) {
                if(err) {
                    console.log('--err checking if product exists');
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    resolve(res)
                }
            });

        }); 
}

var processRecords = function () {

    fetchProducts().then(function(products) { //fetch products to insert

        async.each(products, function(product) {

            checkIfProductExists(product).then(function(result) {
                if(result) {
                    //product exists; move onto the next product
                    callback();
                } else {
                    //product doesn't exist; insert it
                    insertProduct(product);
                    callback();
                }
            });

        }, function(err) {
            if(err) {
                console.log('--async error--');
            }
        });
    }

}

processRecords();
```

However, this logic results in EVERY product in my array being inserted, regardless of whether or not a match was found in my `checkIfProductExists` method... Can someone help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what library is providing that `async.each` function?    Also, if every product is being re-inserted, that just suggests that your `checkIfProductExists` function doesn't return what you think it does.

Comment: Something leveraging `Promise.all` may be your solution, combined with  `array.map`.

Comment: @Alnitak `async.each` is provided by the `async` package - https://www.npmjs.com/package/async

Comment: pushing each promise into an array (inside the loop) and then resolving all of them might be what you're after

Comment: You have an error in your logic. You're using a query to check if the product exists. You haven't accounted for possible false positives there, and the way it's done correctly is by placing a unique constraint on a column that identifies product as unique. What's left is only to insert. If you receive an error about duplicate entry, you know the product is in and you move to the next product. If you use MySQL you can exploit `INSERT IGNORE` syntax which simplifies your code completely. Never check for existence or uniqueness in the app, that's database's job.

Comment: @woolm110 and @ste2425 - this is nothing to do with `Promise.all` - the issue is inside the loop relating to the `checkIfProductExists` call and its result.

Comment: @Alnitak - i updated my question to include my `checkIfProductExists` method

Comment: @Mjh i understand that, but my check logic is much more complex than a simple database constraint can handle so I posted a very watered down version of my check method

Comment: @Alnitak regardless mixing two paradigms for managing async behavior is a recipe for disaster. [heres](https://jsfiddle.net/f644sdtb/) a potential psuedo solution using just `Promises` which would be my personal preferred solution. Obviously this doesn't answer the question just a broader FYI

Comment: @user1547174 since you can collate multiple fields or values and create a hash out of it which uniquely identifies your product, I believe you can use a simple constraint to make a product unique. Anyway, good luck with solving this!

Comment: @ste2425 my point was that `Promise.all` is no use whatsoever if the logic inside the loop isn't working properly

Comment: I think I see your problem - doesn't the `.toArray()` method return an empty array rather than a falsey value if there are no matching records ?

Answer (score 0):

As written, if the `db.find(...).toArray()` call fails to find a matching entry it'll return an *empty array*, not a "false" value.

You should check the *length* of the result from the `checkIfProductExists`, or alternatively have that function resolve to a boolean instead of a potentially empty array, i.e.

```
resolve(res && (res.length > 0));
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to change the default value of asynchronous to false.
The default value is true.

Comment: which asynchronous value are you referring to?

Comment: Refer "dsfq" answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38894659/how-to-replace-async-false-with-promise-in-javascript

Comment: This isn't doing an AJAX request. That `async` calue is for AJAX requests. Furthermore, it's for jQuery, this question doesn't ask about jQuery.